# EF6 API updating data in many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm doing an API with Cards, Effects and Series. A Card can have many Series and many Effects, Series can have many Cards and Effects can have many Cards. I fixed the circular reference, now my problem is, when I want to add/update (using Postman with POST/PUT) for exemple a new Card with existing Serie, it creates a new serie, how can I fix this ?

```
public class Card
{
    public Card()
    {
        this.Effects = new HashSet<Effect>();
        this.Series = new HashSet<Serie>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Number { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Cost { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Element { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Job { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ICollection<Serie> Series { get; set; }

    public int? Strengh { get; set; }

    public string Picture { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Effect> Effects { get; set; }
}

public class Serie
{
    public Serie()
    {
        this.Cards = new HashSet<Card>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Card> Cards { get; set; }
}
```

Here is PUT Request in CardsController

```
    // PUT: api/Cards/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutCard(int id, Card card)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        if (id != card.Id)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        db.Entry(card).State = EntityState.Modified;

        try
        {
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            if (!CardExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }
```

Must I delete and write my own PUT Request or must have to change a config ?

EDIT : I fixed the problem by adding

```
db.Entry(card).State = EntityState.Modified;
foreach (var item in card.Effects)
{
     db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
foreach (var item in card.Series)
{
     db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
db.SaveChanges();
```

But now, it updates nothing, it returns me the card like i want to be, but don't update it in db, any idea ?

Comment: Which EF version?

Comment: I'm using EF6 :o